# i have a spring boot app with JWT token and im giving an arror

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, classnotfoundexception

i am trying to build a spring boot app using JWT token, but it shows me this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:26) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:99) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.JavaInUseSpringSECURITY.JavaInUseSpringSECURITY.JWTTOKEN.JwtUtil.doGenerateToken(JwtUtil.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.JavaInUseSpringSECURITY.JavaInUseSpringSECURITY.JWTTOKEN.JwtUtil.generateToken(JwtUtil.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
```

---

the JwtUtil class is :  I am following everything from a guy using this strategy:
https://www.javainuse.com/webseries/spring-security-jwt/chap4

```
@Service
public class JwtUtil {

    private String secret;
    private int jwtExpirationInMs;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    @Value("${jwt.jwtExpirationInMs}")
    public void setJwtExpirationInMs(int jwtExpirationInMs) {
        this.jwtExpirationInMs = jwtExpirationInMs;
    }

    // generate token for user
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities();
        if (roles.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))) {
            claims.put("isAdmin", true);
        }
        if (roles.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))) {
            claims.put("isUser", true);
        }
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }


    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject)
.setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtExpirationInMs)).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
    }

}
```

I was expecting to get the token from postman using POST,BODY,JSON and giving username and password,
but i am getting :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-31T16:35:00.188+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/authenticate"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could it be that you are missing a dependency?

A quick internet search shows that this class is part of [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api) library

Comment: yeah it was missing a dependency but the dependencies showed from the guy above helped me solve this. Can you please show me the way you made this google search? I wanna have a general idea of how to search stuff as a newbie. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you added all the required dependencies:

add these dependencies, and  make sure you add the jwt dependencies below as well:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

extra dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
                <version>0.11.5</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Yeah it worked now,, thanks a lot. But i dont get it why the guy in the video is not using these dependencies instead he is just using :  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
   <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.1</version>
  </dependency>   ,,   can you also tell me what kind of google search did u make to find these? I just wanna have an idea of internet search of stuff.. Thanks in advance and hope you have a great day

Comment: Good, mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. 
I went throw this error when I was learning myself. Try to understand the error, because sometimes you need to know what you are searching for instead of pasting the stack trace. 
Stackoverflow should be your first choice to go with. Also use mvn repository website to get and check your dependencies. Lastly, whenever you are using a library read the release notes to see the new changes.

Comment: lol you marked the wrong post; my post is above, the one with the code....you welcome anyway.

Comment: probably you are using new java version (17) where javax packages were replaced by jakarta and jjwt lib is not java 17 ready yet